# SQL syntax issue with Discord bot development (mySQL 8.0)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know this issue has been handled before on this website, but I have tried everything I have seen and for some season nothing works... so it might be something more specific. Again, I apologize if I might have missed something but I am new and frustrated with why this isn't working...

My code is this:

```
bot.on(`message`, async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  con.query(`SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    var sql;

    if(rows.length < 1) {
      var sql = (`INSERT INTO profile (id, username) VALUES (${message.author.id}, ${message.author.tag})`);
    };

    con.query(sql, console.log);
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
```

I am trying to get the person's Discord ID and username to be placed in the database. I have dozens of different configurations for this code and it keeps giving me syntax errors. I have noticed mySQL 8.0 have very different syntax requirements compared to other tutorials I have watched. I have referenced the mySQL website to try and figure out my problem. I have spent 2 days on this issue and I am at the end of my rope, so I am asking for help!

Thanks in advance for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance the quotes in your second query are missing. Assuming both fields are string types, it should look something like this:

```
sql = (`INSERT INTO profile (id, username) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', '${message.author.tag})'`);
```

(If `id` or `username` are not strings, but number types, you might drop the respective `'`.)

Comment: The ID is a set of 18 numbers, so I removed the ' 's as well. I tried doing what you suggested and I am still getting a syntax error. I don't know how many times I have  ran this and it keeps failing on that line. Clearly there is something wrong, I just can't figure out what...

Comment: " sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\' at line 1'," when I put the ' 's in, but  "code: 'ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE'" when I don't put the ' 's around the id, which is an 18 digit number. In mySQL/database, I do have the type for ID set to Int(18) and Varchar(30) for the username.

Comment: @Zarvix 18 digits are too much for a plain INT (caps at around 9 digits). Try using `BIGINT` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` as a type (caps at 18-19 digits).

Comment: This time I get this error after changing the type to BIGINT... "code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD', sqlMessage: 'Field \'Name\' doesn\'t have a default value'," I haven't seen this error before when trying to figure this out. "Name" is a name I am going to be setting up to allow people on the server to create a RP character by the bot asking questions and currently set up in the database. The replies will be stored in the database for easy retrieval by members when battling. So, I will have values for name eventually. Should I change the NOT NULL's to NULL until I get profile creations working?

Comment: @Zarvix Would be  one option. You need some value at insertion time for each `NOT NULL` field or provide a default value at table creation.

Comment: I changed all the values for everything except ID and username to null and it worked! Thanks so much! :D